# What is the best way of handling sessions on the server when using frontend Firebase Auth?

Tags: .net, firebase, firebase-authentication, maui

I'm creating a .NET MAUI app that uses Firebase Auth for its authentication. While the login itself is handled on the frontend, I'd like a way for the server to know if my user has an active session. The only way I've found is to send an ID token with every request and then verify if the user is logged in there, but that seems a bit clumsy.

Is there a better way to handle the session (for example, sending the token when the user logs in and then creating a session on the backend) or at least automatically send the ID token without having to manually include it in each post?

Thanks for any answers or help!

Comment: sending a token on every request is usually how session is handled.  You can create a base class that automatically includes in the header of every request

Comment: Sending the token with every request is standard practice.